# How to align several tables in td in center in Email Html Template

Tags: html, css, email

I am trying to center all tables in td. Solution should work good in email clients such as outlook, Windows Live e.t.c. But they align vertically. How to align tables in center of div?

```
    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;width:100%;" width="100%">
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/facebook.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=vk.com">Share</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=vk.com&amp;mini=true&amp;title=" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/linkedin.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=vk.com&amp;mini=true&amp;title=">Share</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=: vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/twitter.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=: vk.com">Tweet</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/google-plus.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=vk.com">+1</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/vkontakte.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=vk.com">Share</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Tables within tables.... **Why god?! Why do you do this to us!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because what LcSalazar you can not disagree with him,
 but I assume you are making layout for email and there is just the "table layout" way if you want the **outlook** to display what you expect
so the `table` contains `rows` and `columns`
if you want the `table` content to display in one line you should divide that line in how much `columns` you need and then put inside the content in separate `tables`

```
<table>
    <tbody>  
        <tr>
           <td>
                <!-- table content 1 -->
           </td>
            <td>
                <!-- table content 2 -->
           </td>
            <td>
                <!-- table content 3 -->
           </td>
            <td>
                <!-- table content 4 -->
           </td>
            <td>
                <!-- table content 5 -->
           </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>   
</table>
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I want to create email template. Your answer is good, I have already tried it. But here is some problem. If we have  many tables or if width of table is bigger then we expect we need to create two rows.

Comment: you should use pixels for global table to set the width and then use % for inner tables so it sits in the outer table size
and if you need to create two rows then just add them in outer table - in my experience start on paper and draw tables so you know what are you doing it gets very messy

Comment: and just a suggestion use CSS styling for debug purposes to draw borders in different colors for each table or sector you are working with

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not going to enter in the matter of why you should reconsider your layout, so you wouldn't need nested tables... Neither should use table for layout... Also, why shouldn't you use so many inline styles... I'm simply going to answer your question as it is...*

Here it goes:

A `table` by default acts like a block element, using full width and breaking the line.

To place them side-by-side, change their `display` property to `inline-table`

```css
table table {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;width:100%;" width="100%">
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/facebook.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=vk.com">Share</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=vk.com&amp;mini=true&amp;title=" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/linkedin.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=vk.com&amp;mini=true&amp;title=">Share</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=: vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/twitter.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=: vk.com">Tweet</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/google-plus.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=vk.com">+1</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table align="center" class="cell-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;;margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:left;background-color:#ffffff;border:none;;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="33" align="left" class="social-share-cell" style="padding:2px;"><a href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=vk.com" title=""><img alt="" src="http:///client/Content/images//social-links/vkontakte.png" width="33" height="33"></a></td>
            <td class="social-share-cell" style="padding:0 5px 0 3px;vertical-align: middle;" align="left"><a href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=vk.com">Share</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it works in browsers, but I forgot to say that I am making alyout for email template. And your code snipped doesn't work in outlook:(

Comment: @Radislav - You need to make the email requirement more clear in your question.

Comment: @Radislav - I understand. But as to your specific question *How to align several tables in td in center*, with the provided code and info, it is answered...

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

add this style "display: inline-table;" for table remove the text-align:left; from table style .